# How to programmatically reset user password

Tags: 8, users

I'm trying to create a custom module for resetting the user's password.

In the following block of code I'm attempting to get the password in hash form:

```
$pass='User123@';

$autoloader =require_once(\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('autoload.php'));
//echo $autoloader; exit;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod', FALSE);
$kernel->boot();
$password_hasher = $kernel->getContainer()->get('password');
$newhash =  $password_hasher->hash($pass);

//echo  $newhash ; exit;
```

This is my db update code:

```
 $updatepass = \Drupal::database()->update('users_field_data')
      ->fields(array(
        'pass' => $newhash,
      ))
      ->condition('name', "$id",'=')
      ->execute();
```

Please help me understand what mistake I've made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`setPassword()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Entity!User.php/function/User%3A%3AsetPassword/8.2.x) method to update the user's password:

```
// Get user storage object.
$user_storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('user');

// Load user by their user ID
$user = $user_storage->load($id);

// Set the new password
$user->setPassword('User123@');

// Save the user
$user->save();
```

This will take care of all the hashing for you and will trigger all the appropriate hooks for saving a user.

Comment: Thank you for your response  what about where condition i want to create a modules where admin can update password for other user

Comment: So in this example we are loading a user with a specific id. The id is in the variable ``$id`. You are responsible for populating this value. So we are updating the users password _where_ the id is equal to whatever value you provide.

Comment: Also there is already core functionality for admins to update users passwords. Why do you want to duplicate this?